# Difference between dates in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a problem with dates in R. Define T1 and T2 as dates in POSIXct or POSIXlt format with 6 fractional seconds:

```
 op <- options(digits.secs = 6)
 T1 = strptime("2015.10.10 12:00:00.150150", "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%OS")
 T2 = strptime("2015.10.10 16:30:15.212412", "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

How to get difference between T1 and T2 in this format:

```
format = "%H:%M:%OS"
```

For example difference between defined dates is:

```
diff = "04:30:15.062262"
```

I tried different approaches, but it wasn't successful.

My attempts:

```
T1 = strptime("2015.10.10 12:00:00.150150", "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%OS")
T2 = strptime("2015.10.10 16:30:15.212412", "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%OS")
h = difftime(T2,T1, units = "hours")
m = difftime(T2,T1, units = "mins")
s = difftime(T2,T1, units = "secs")
```

But I don't know how to get fractionals.

Comment: Please show us what you tried. Then we know if we have to tweak your existing solution, or provide a new altogether. As a general tip, I use the `lubridate` package for everything related to time and dates. I think studying the docs of that package will get you quite far.

Comment: Hm, it is a good question! I expected `as.difftime(T2 - T1, format='%H:%M:%OS')` to work, but it is not. I don't understand the down votes...

Comment: With `lubridate` there is a nice function to get a similar output but not exactly the same format... `lubridate::seconds_to_period(difftime(T2,T1, units='secs'))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the code is self-explainable

```
x <- as.numeric(difftime(T2,T1,units = "sec")) # diff in sec
hrs <- floor(x/3600) # get the hours
x <- x%%3600         # update the x after removing the hrs(in sec)  
min <- floor(x/60)   # get the minutes
sec <- x%%60         # get the sec

paste(hrs,min,sec,sep= ":")
# [1] "4:30:15.0622620582581"
```

Comment: I need only 6 fractional seconds, but it's simple to cut this string. Thank you, it works.

Comment: @AslanBayramkulov yeah...`sprintf`, `format()` all would help you!